# Connecting 7" flex duct to roof exhaust

Tags: hvac

I have a 7" flex duct from the microwave that I'm trying to connect to the existing exhaust pipe in the roof. The fitting is fairly close to 7" and has an inner rib/ring. When I connect the two, the flex duct just falls back out. Is there anything I can do to make it stay? Maybe mastic?

[image]

Comment: Is it a trick of the photo, or is the hole partially blocked by ragged wood pieces (i.e. partially blocked/not round)?

Comment: Somewhat of an illusion. The wood piece just barely allows the duct to be inserted.

Comment: they make a special tape for ducts. it's gray. normally you would use a clamp like a hose clamp. you can fashion a garrote from steel wire and tack it to the wood to hold it secure, then tape around the seam.

Comment: @dandavis Well, you learn something everyday! I didn't know what 'garrote' was, but I must admit that the 1st definition is somewhat disturbing: "kill (someone) by strangulation, typically with an iron collar or a length of wire or cord.
"he had been garroted with piano wire"" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "duct starting collar" like this:

[image: duct starting collar]
<sup>Image courtesy of lowes.com</sup>

In your case, I would put the small fingers pointing up (turn the image upside down), then screw the flange of the collar onto the wood surrounding the hole. This will attach the collar to the house.

Then you slide your duct around the remainder of the starting collar and use 3-4 self-drilling sheet metal screws to attach the flex duct to the collar. Wrap some foil based *duct* tape around the end of the flex duct, covering the edge of the duct and the screws. Do not use the cloth-based "duck" tape for this. It just won't last as long as "duct" tape will for this purpose. It's worth the few extra bucks to pick up a roll of the proper stuff.

7" is an unusual size (in my experience) for ducting, so you may have a bit of an issue finding a 7" starting collar. If you cannot, you might try contacting some HVAC companies in your area to see if one of them would be willing to find & sell you one, or, possibly, fab one for you. Otherwise, you might have to get "creative" in adapting an 8" collar to fit.

---

The crimps in the collar (at the top of the picture above) are designed to make the 8" diameter pipe slightly smaller to fit inside another 8" pipe. You may be able to squeeze them enough to make them fit inside your 7" pipe.

If you can do that, you'd probably need to attach the collar to the duct *first*, using a piece of wood as a backer to drive the screws through the duct and the crimped collar to ensure they grab both pieces of metal. Once you're sure you've got a good mechanical connection with the screws, tape it up.

Then, once you've got the duct on the collar, put it in the hole in the ceiling (which may have to be made larger to match) and screw it in place through the flange.

Comment: Shouldn't have a problem finding 7" starting collars, they are fairly common in HVAC. Maybe not at HD or Lowes, but Fergusson definitely has them.

Comment: I did say "(in my experience)", @GlenYates. Thanks for pointing this out.